# Unity3D - How to control Light.Intensity without animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, light

I have the following animation:

See on video: [Animation Light](http://youtu.be/NNdfJYB-drE)

***Note: Below image of animation control***

[image]

How can I get the same result using a script? My intention is that the script has no "if".

***Don't like this:***

```
    public float minIntensity;
    public float maxIntensity;

    public float intensityAmount;

    private Light light;

    void Awake(){
        light  = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    void Update(){

        if (light.intensity > maxIntensity) {
            light.intensity -= intensityAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (light.intensity < minIntensity) {
            light.intensity += intensityAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        }   


    }
```

I wonder if there is any possibility to do this using some native function ... like: (Math.Clamp, Math.Lerp, Quaternion.Slerp) without any condition as "if" in the code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well like you mentioned, you can just use a clamp:

```
light.intensity = Mathf.Clamp(value, minIntensity, maxIntensity)
```

However, despite the lack of detail on what type of animation you want, I am assuming you want to "ping pong" between the min and the max. If that is the case, we can use our friendly neighborhood sine wave for that.

```
public float Frequency = 10f;  
public float Magnitude = 2f;

void Update() {
    light.Intensity = Magnitude + Mathf.Sin(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * Frequency) * Magnitude;
}
```

The sine wave will go from -1 to 1, the magnitude value will make it go from (-magnitude to +magnitude) Since we don't want a negative light intensity, we add magnitude to the start, so the end result is (0 to 2 * magnitude) You can change this to work however you desire, but the point should be clear.

The Frequency variable will change how fast we animate back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is not clear to you? Please see the video and see the backlight control. It partially works, it needs the value to work from 4! intensity MIN = 4  intensity MAX  = 7. Interpolate between this values.

Comment: @igao, you can use a 'baseMagnitude' of 5.5 and a 'varMagnitude' of 1.5, so :: light.Intensity = baseMagnitude + Mathf.Sin(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * Frequency) * varMagnitude; // This way the value of the equation will be on your desired range (5.5 - 1.5 = 4 and 5.5 + 1.5 = 7 )